# Why can't I access my Windows Users folder in Linux subsystem for Windows

Tags: linux, windows-10

I have installed ubuntu for my Linux subsystem for Windows

[image]

When I try to access my `Users` folder on my host machine I get that it does not exist.

Do I need to do some kind of mounting the folder or what? I need to access my `.ssh` folder under `C:/Users/MyUser/.ssh` from within the Linux subsystem, how do I do that when I get this message?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the correct directory name:

```
/mnt/c/Windows/System32$ cd /mnt/c/Users/
/mnt/c/Users$
```

**Note:**

The message that appears in one of the screenshots you posted says that the directory `mnt/c/User` does not exist. This is reasonable: if you want to access `C:\Users` you should issue the command: `cd /mnt/c/Users/`. One difference is the trailing `s` in `Users` vs `User`, the other is the starting `/` in `/mnt` which makes the current directory irrelevant as opposed to `mnt` which only works if issued from the `/` location.

Comment: So what you mean is I need to cd into `/mnt/c/Windows/System32` ? and from there cd into `/mnt/c/Users` ?  if so that does not work either

Comment: @Yantes The starting directory is irrelevant. The folder you want to move to is `/mnt/c/Users/` as opposed to `mnt/c/User` as shown in your screenshot.

Comment: ahh yeah okay I see know :p xD Thanks @simlev and It is of course not called `User` but `Users`

Comment: You can always use tab completion to help.  Type cd /mint/c/Us[tab] and it should complete the rest (assuming there is only one match).  If there’s more than one match, tab will complete all the common characters and stop there. Pressing tab again will show all the possible answers.  Type some more to try and make the match unique and press tab again to complete.  This method will also auto-escape spaces if needed.  This functionality is basic shell functionality in Linux.